# In Download POP UP menu my downloaded filename was not showing full with extension

Tags: java, servlets

Hi i am facing issue when download a filename using servlet . the downloaded file is not with proper filename .It downloaded with half filename with no extension can you please suggest . In below code as i debug in filename variable filename is proper but when download pop up open it show half file name with no extension and file download with half filename with no etension . Please suggest me below is my code

```
     String fileName = retrievedFile.getLocation();
        byte[] fileContent = retrievedFile.getContent();
        InputStream decodedContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);
        int contentLength = getFileSize(decodedContent);
        response.setContentLength(contentLength);
        response.setContentType("application/x-file-download");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","");
        response.setHeader("Pragma","");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName);
        ServletOutputStream out =  response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = decodedContent.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the closing " in the content disposition header.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing doublequotes

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName+"\"");
```